# Mono-Develop throws error "" when trying to create select Gtk objects (dialogs), why?

Tags: mono, dialog, gtk, monodevelop

I've recently started playing with Mono (1.9.1) on Ubuntu 8.04 with the Mono-Develop IDE (v1). I am attempting to use GTK-Sharp 2 to run the GUI for the play apps.

For some reason when I try to create gtk dialogs (`ColorSelectionDialog` or `MessageDialog`) the compiler throws the error "'Gtk.ColorSelectionDialog.ColorSelectionDialog(GLib.GType)' is inaccessible due to its protection level(CS0122)"

Perhaps these dialogs are not public objects in the GTK Libary?

Here is a sample of some c# code that throws the exception:

```
Gtk.ColorSelectionDialog dlg = new Gtk.ColorSelectionDialog(); //dont need any more than this
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution. Can't use the default constructor with no arguments. For some reason this constructor just doesn't work. If it's called like such:

```
MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog (parent_window, 
                                  DialogFlags.DestroyWithParent,
                              MessageType.Error, 
                                  ButtonsType.Close, "Error loading file");
```

Then it works ok. Obviously something is buggered up somewhere, but I don't have the technical know how to figure out how to fix the underlying problem in either Gtk or Mono.